# How to scrape data with authentication where my login page and profile have the same url?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to scrape data from my profile but the website I use has the same URL for both login and Profile .so for this

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' :  password})
opener.open('http://www.example.com/login.php', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://www.example.com/hiddenpage.php')
print resp.read()
```

Comment: Use a `requests.Session()`, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects , I also imagine there is a redirect on successful login, can you share the url?

Comment: @Praneth, the url for the  page  you see after logging in is not the same as the url you use to logic, also the data is completely dynamically created so even loggin in you will get very little useful I imagine, in fact it is identical to if you just did a get to "http://demo.traccar.org/

Comment: So what should i do to extract the data from my profile after logging in @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 1):

@Padraic Cunningham beat me to it, but the requests module is what you need

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

```
import requests

username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'

s = requests.session()
l = {'username': username,
           'j_password': password}
s.post('http://www.example.com/login.php', data=login)
s.get('http://www.example.com/hiddenpage.php')
```